# valid xpath expression from html

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i ha ve this html

```
<yt-formatted-string id="text" class="style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default">
All
</yt-formatted-string><paper-ripple class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-button">
```

this xpath works with selenium python

```
//yt-formatted-string[text()='All']
```

but how can i include the part id="text" of the html to my xpath expression to be valid
to find with selelnium python

thanks a lot

Comment: just a tip if you don't know, you can always right click on the element in Insepct Element and choose copy >> copy XPATH...will save you a lot of time :)

Comment: If you know the element id, why would you use xpath at all?  Finding an element by its id is better.

Comment: id is not unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
//yt-formatted-string[@id='text' and text()='All']
```

or the more general approach

```
//yt-formatted-string[@id='text' and contains(text(),'All')]
```